# Can't import modules - ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, django, scrapy, pycharm, python-import

I've created a new app called `engineapp`. Inside this app, there is a folder `engine` which is a `Scrapy` project.

When I try to import model from `storage` app inside `top.py` file, it returns:

```
from storage.models import TopItem
ImportError: No module named storage.models
```

Or the similar problem, when I try to import settings of scrapy project:

```
from engineapp.engine.engine import settings
```

It returns:

```
from engineapp.engine.engine import settings
ImportError: No module named engineapp.engine.engine
```

This is when I run scrapy project from command line.

Both imports created `PyCharm` itself.

As you can see, I've added `__init__()` everywhere so python would be able to recognize those files.

Do you know what should I do to be able to import those files?

[image]

Comment: I've had a similar issue like this with nested packages of the same name (like `engine` here), when multiple folders along the nested path are in your (Pycharm project settings') PYTHONPATH env variable. Does it work outside of Pycharm?

Comment: It doesn't work outside. As I said, I'm running command scrapy crawl spider_name. That's where those errors occures. PyCharm thinks that everything is ok.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik wait, it works IN pycharm but NOT from the terminal?

Comment: every autoimport from pycharm does not always guarentee that it will be imported perfectly while running the code

Comment: No no. There is a command line in PyCharm. I can run it only from command line so I tried to run it using this cmd. The import error occured. I tried already Windows command line and the same problem occured. It does not have to do anything with PyCharm.

Comment: your engine directory just below the engineapp does not contain any init.py? so i think error is coming from that reason

Comment: Both contains __init__.py You can see it on the picture.,

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik why would you have tagged this as `pycharm` if this isn't a pycharm issue?

Comment: Because PyCharm autocompletes these settings and doesn't detect any problem.

Comment: @NickChapman issue has wrong autocomplete from pycharm and can't import module from python side.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm autocomplete relies on different IDE settings. You've marked your `realstate_scanner` as sources root, so PyCharm can resolve imports for this. From docs:

> These roots contain the actual source files and resources. PyCharm uses the source roots as the starting point for resolving imports.

If you can't import some module in python, you should check PATH/PYTHONPATH variables first to make sure python interpreter knows where to find your module.